# What kind of loop is for (;;)?

Tags: c, for-loop, kernel, mutex

Found in torvalds/linux-2.6.git -> kernel/mutex.c line 171

I have tried to find it on Google and such to no avail.

What does `for (;;)` instruct?

Comment: that's not a helpful comment. Just because konman isn't that well versed in C doesn't mean they can't read code files. And now they have learned something, so that's a good thing.

Comment: I agree with Alastair. Reading source written by others is a great way to learn.

Comment: If you aren't well-versed in c, read kernel code.

Comment: @Kim Despite the protests, your point is valid. It's true that the OP learned something -- but by asking a question at SO, not by reading the kernel code. There are far more efficient ways to learn than to read code in a language one doesn't even know the basics of and then ask SO about every little thing one doesn't understand.

Comment: P.S. Most of the answers here are misleading. `for(;;)` is not (necessarily) an "infinite" loop, it's simply a loop that doesn't test the condition in the `for(...)` construct itself. This is particularly relevant in the code cited by the OP -- the very first statement inside the loop is `if (...) break;`, and there are several other conditional breaks in the loop as well; nothing at all "infinite" about it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The for(;;) is an infinite loop condition, similar to while(1) as most have already mentioned. You would more often see this, in kernel mutex codes, or mutex eg problem such as dining philosophers. Until the mutex variable is set to a particular value, such that a second process gets access to the resource, the second process keeps on looping, also known as busy wait. Access to a resource can be disk access, for which 2 process are competing to gain access using a mutex such that at a time only one process has the access to the resource.

Comment: Infinite loops and busy waits are different things. A busy wait is a *sleepless* loop waiting for some condition -- nothing infinite about it.

Comment: @Jim, to be fair, no loop is infinite as you could lose power at any moment or your machine will die of old age. He's talking more about asking the compiler for a loop with no end condition than actually something infinite.

Comment: @Blindy Way to miss the point and be absurdly pedantic at the same time. Like duh, I didn't know about the heat death of the universe. Meanwhile, *busy* waits are, as I said, sleepless, *and* have end conditions.

Answer (score 46):

It literally means "do nothing, until nothing happens and at each step, do nothing to prepare for the next". Basically, it's an infinite loop that you'll have to break somehow from within using a `break`, `return` or `goto` statement.

Answer (score 9):

It is an infinite loop which has no initial condition, no increment condition and no end condition. So it will iterate forever equivalent to while(1).

Comment: at least one compiler I know will warn about while ( 1 ) or while ( true ) loops, but "know" to not produce diagnostics for ( ; ; ) as it is considered the "standard" form for infinite loop.

Answer (score 5):

It loops forever (until the code inside the loop calls `break` or `return`, of course. `while(1)` is equivalent, I personally find it more logical to use that.

Comment: Or calls exit or longjmp or does a goto out of the loop, or (POSIX) until a signal occurs that does not return. Also various sorts of undefined behavior can terminate the loop, as well as various external events beyond the scope of the C language, including dropping a nuke on the computer on which the program is running.

Answer (score 4):

It's equivalent to `while( true )`

Edit:  Since there's been some debate sparked by my answer (good debate, mind you) it should be clarified that this is not entirely accurate for C programs not written to C99 and beyond wherein stdbool.h has set the value of true = 1.

Comment: They need a comment downvoting system.

Comment: Hey man, he's just trying to make sure people future-proof their applications against the possibility of the value of 'true' changing.

Comment: Ugh, the pain of a language where "1" is a more authoritative "True" value than a boolean "true".

Comment: @Blindy: Why would you downvote his comment? @Frank: Changing from what? true is not defined in standard C.

Comment: In most languages true means !0

Comment: @GregS: No. Provided that true != 0 :)

Comment: @sepp2k: `true` is defined in `stdbool.h` of C99

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but I doubt the linux kernel uses C99.

Comment: Is that really worth to argue? And i cannot see any reason for downvoting this answer (i see this answer is downvoted). GregS' comment may be counted as a contribution to answer. And we provided the info that **true** is not defined in some versions of C.

Comment: @Ton:  In most langages, true doesn't mean !0.  Most of them have true/false concepts that aren't just arithmetic operations or values, and those that don't often have other concepts.  In Common Lisp, `nil` or `()` is false, and everything else is true.  In Perl, `""` is one possible false value.

Comment: +1 to counter the undeserved (especially since the edit) downvote.

Answer (score 2):

it is an infinite for loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is same  as writing  infinite loop using " for " statement but u have to use break or some  other statement that can get out of this loop.

Answer (score 1):

I means:

```
#define EVER ;;

for(EVER)
{
     // do something
}
```

**Warning: Using this in your code is highly discouraged.**

Comment: I really hate it when I see code like this. The author obviously think he is more clear but I often have to back and make sure that EVER isn't defined as something bad that will cause me problem.

Comment: True, i would not write for(EVER) in my code either. This is just for fun :)

Answer (score 1):

> for(;;)

is an infinite loop just like `while(1)`. Here no condition is given that will terminate the loop. If you are not breaking it using `break` statement this loop will never come to an end.

Answer (score 1):

It is functionally equivilent to `while(true) { }`.

The reason why the `for(;;)` syntax is sometimes preferred comes from an older age where `for(;;)` actually compiled to a slightly faster machine code than `while(TRUE) {}`. This is because `for(;;) { foo(); }` will translate in the first pass of the compiler to:

```
lbl_while_condition:
   mov $t1, 1
   cmp $t1, 0
   jnz _exit_while
lbl_block:
   call _foo
   jmp lbl_while_condition
```

whereas the `for(;;)` would compile in the first pass to:

```
lbl_for_init:
   ; do nothing
lbl_for_condition:
   ; always
lbl_for_block:
   call foo;
lbl_for_iterate:
   ; no iterate
   jmp lbl_for_condition
```

i.e.

```
 lbl_for_ever:
    call foo
    jmp lbl_for_ever
```

Hence saving 3 instructions on every pass of the loop.

In practice however, both statements have long since been not only functionally equivalent, but also actually equivalent, since optimisations in the compiler for all builds other than debug builds will ensure that the `mov`, `cmp` and `jnz` are optimised away in the `while(1)` case, resulting in optimal code for both `for(;;)` and `while(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

That was obviously an infinite loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop that you'll have to break somehow from within using a break, return or goto statement.
or either some interrupt happens otherwise this loop will run infinitely and executes ;(null statement) every time