# Why Does Test Condition of "for(;;)" Succeed?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, for-loop, infinite-loop

Insomuch as I understand "for(;;)" has no initial condition, no test condition and no increment condition, and therefore loops forever, I am curious why the test condition succeeds each loop.

Does the empty expression ";" evaluate as true in C? Or is this a special case handled by compilers?

[A similar, but unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991670/what-kind-of-loop-is-for).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is by the definition of the `for` statement in the C language.  6.8.5.3/2 "The `for` statement":

> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted.  *An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a
>   nonzero constant*.

Comment: Here is a link to the current draft C99 specification: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf . The for-loop specification is on page 136.

Answer (score 5):

C language has no such thing as "empty expression". If any expression is missing from the `for` statement, syntactically it means that the entire expression is *omitted*, not that it is there, but empty.

A `for` loop with an omitted second expression loops forever because the specification of `for` statement says so. I.e. it is a dedicated feature specific to `for` alone, not something more generic.

Additionaly (a terminological nitpick) only the second expression is really a *condition*. The first and the third are not really "conditions".